# Non parametric Monte Carlo estimation in R

Tags: r, monte-carlo, quantiles

Let's say that we have a dataset of a single vector :

```
xx <- c(1.99, -0.424, 5.61, -3.13, -2.24, -0.14, -3.32, -0.837, -1.98, -0.120,
          7.81, -3.13, 1.20, 1.54, -0.594, 1.05, 0.192, -3.83, -0.522, 0.605,
          0.427, 0.276, 0.784, -1.30, 0.542, -0.159, -1.66, -2.46, -1.81, -0.412,
          -9.67, 6.61, -0.589, -3.42, 0.036, 0.851, -1.34, -1.22, -1.47, -0.592,
          -0.311, 3.85, -4.92, -0.112, 4.22, 1.89, -0.382, 1.20, 3.21, -0.648,
          -0.523, -0.882, 0.306, -0.882, -0.635, 13.2, 0.463, -2.60, 0.281, 1.00,
          -0.336, -1.69, -0.484, -1.68, -0.131, -0.166, -0.266, 0.511, -0.198, 1.55,
          -1.03, 2.15, 0.495, 6.37, -0.714, -1.35, -1.55, -4.79, 4.36, -1.53,
          -1.51, -0.140, -1.10, -1.87, 0.095, 48.4, -0.998, -4.05, -37.9, -0.368,
          5.25, 1.09, 0.274, 0.684, -0.105, 20.3, 0.311, 0.621, 3.28, 1.56)
```

the Empirical quantile of the xx vector is :

```
quantile(xx,0.01)
     1% 
-9.9523
```

If I want to estimate it with Monte Carlo method I can do something like the code below which randomly samples 2  1-day observations from the empirical distribution and add them up. Repeat 100,000 times and then I calculate the quantile of $\alpha=0.01$

```
alpha = 0.01
set.seed(123789)
rvec <- rep(0,100000)
for (i in 1:2) {
  rvec <- rvec+ sample(xx,100000,replace=TRUE) }
quantile(rvec,0.01)
```

But the result is far away from the empirical quantile.What is that happening? And how I can improve it ?

Comment: Have you plotted the distribution of `rvec` at the end? How does it compare to the original distribution?

Comment: 1) you are taking way more samples than you actually have data, which is probably wrong, 2) you repeat this sampling two times and then add the two vectors together by summing them, so why do you expect this to be the same as your original data?

Comment: @user2974951 I want to simulate a forecast for 2 days ahead.

Comment: @Dave both histogram plot are similar.The simulated version are just thinner because of the larger sample

Comment: `But the result is far away from the empirical quantile` how did you obtain this? How are you comparing these results?

Comment: @user2974951 comparing the two quantile results

Comment: I don't understand. You have only 1 data set, the xx vector? And in your simulation you basically do xx+xx and then compare this to xx (by comparing the quantiles of xx+xx and xx)? Again, why do you expect these two distributions to be similar?

Comment: @user2974951 you are right.But is there any other way simulating this datset with a non parametric way ?

Comment: What you are doing is not necessarily wrong, but xx+xx cannot be compared to xx, these are two different distributions. You would need to have an additional "real" xx+xx vector, and then you could compare these two distributions. Otherwise you will have to make some assumptions.

Comment: Why do you want to simulate the data? You have the data. Do you want some kind of alternative estimator of the quantile (as opposed to the quantile function in R)? Do you want a confidence interval for the quantile? // You seem to indicate that xx is a time series, which complicates matters. Could you please elaborate on what you want to do with the time series?

Comment: @Dave yes yesterday I posted a similar question concerning bootstrap simulation on time series [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568848/value-at-risk-from-bootstrap-bca-quantiles).Yes the xx vector I assume it is a time series.My actual goal is that the data have lag 2.Now if I draw 100000 times 2 days ahead I will forecast non parametrically this time series

Comment: What does the quantile have to do with forecasting the time series?

Comment: @Dave I try to forecast the value at risk for 2 days horizon.I know that there is a serial autocorrelation and some models such arch or garch might be suitable but now I am concerning only the non parametric approach

Comment: Then you have an estimate of your quantity of interest. What’s the problem? Yes, it disagrees with another estimate of that value, but that’s the point of using an alternative estimate. (If an alternative estimator always gave the same estimates, it wouldn’t be much of an alternative.)

Comment: Just as with your other questions, this one lacks clarity. For example: 1. You say "single vector" but you mean "time series". 2. You don't mention any assumptions about this time series. 3. You use the *quantile* function to compute a point estimate of the quantile (ignoring completely the time series nature of *xx*) but what you seem to want is a quantile function at every point in time. 4. It's also unclear what's part of the problem and what's part of your proposed solution (which might or not might make sense). 5. The problem might not make sense in the first place.